# a way to search between some points and find important points

Tags: math, linear-algebra

I have some points, which are in order, which are drawn by user.

I want to find important points between these points. Important point, as I define, is a point where we have a sudden change in direction of points. For example, the 'Z' drawn by hand, has to has 2 important points.

I tried computing angle between adjacent points, but this is not giving me desired result. And computing the change in slope is the same.

Maybe I need to optimize the angle finding somehow, but I have no idea. Any idea?

Edit: here is Java code to compare angles:

```
int nBreakPoints = 0;
double nextangle = 0;
double nextr;
double r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points[1].x-points[0].x, 2) 
    + Math.pow(points[1].y-points[0].y, 2));
double angle = Math.asin((points[1].y-points[0].y) / r)*180/Math.PI; 
double cumR = r;
int firstI = 0;
for(int i=1; i<points.length-2 ;i++)
{
    nextr = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points[i].x-points[i+1].x, 2) 
        + Math.pow(points[i+1].y-points[i].y, 2));
    cumR += nextr;
    if(cumR < 20 || cumR==0) continue;
    nextangle = Math.asin((points[i].y-points[firstI].y) / cumR)*180/Math.PI;
    if(Math.abs(angle-nextangle) >= 20) nBreakPoints++;
    r = nextr;
    angle = nextangle;
    cumR = 0;
    firstI = i;
}
```

Ok, it just computes angle between two points, and if they are different than 20 degrees, we have a new important point.

Just to note, `cumR` and `firstI` are added to prevent "too close" points to be brought into computation.

Comment: Why doesn't computing the angle not give the desired result?

Comment: As the points are drawn by hand and sampled, maybe the user just doesn't draw the 'Z' as sharp as he/she should. So it won't count in this way. I will try to post some codes to show what I have done.

Comment: Copy the lines, sharpen the copy and compute the angle.

Comment: The question is how to sharpen the line.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I had to sleep! And how to sharpen the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angle calculation may fail if the angle flips by 360°. E.g. one angle is 179° and the next one is -179°. The absolute difference is pretty big, but the angles are pretty close.

Here is a more robust method:

```
pp = points[i - 1] //the preceding point; if it exists
p = points[i]
pn = points[i + 1] //the next point; if it exists
dp = [p.x - pp.x, p.y - pp.y] //direction of incoming line
dn = [pn.x - p.x, pn.y - p.y] //direction of outgoing line
r = Math.sqrt((dp.x * dp.x + dp.y * dp.y) * (dn.x * dn.x + dn.y * dn.y)) //product of vector lengths
cos = (dp.x * dn.x + dp.y * dn.y) / r //cosine of angle
angle = Math.acos(cos) * 180 / Math.PI;
if(angle > 20)
    ...
```

If the points are very near to each other and subject to noise, it might be reasonable to consider a wider range instead of adjacent points:

```
pp = points[i - n]
p = points[i]
pn = points[i + n]
```

`n` can be a constant that you can choose based on the application. You could also look for the next point with a certain distance to the current one:

```
for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
{
    dp = [p.x - points[j].x, p.y - points[j].y]
    rp = dp.x * dp.x + dp.y * dp.y;
    if(rp > square_threshold)
        break;
}
```

... and the same for the next point.